# Processing.JS Error - TypeError: e is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype, processing

I'm having this strange error on [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/cs/dev-khan-logins-2014/5845868966576128), which I figured out the Login.prototype.* is causing the issue, and I can't find a workaround. Here is the errors Firefox printed into the development console.

TypeError: mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create jshint.js:8417

TypeError: e is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem I was having, I was passing 'undefined' as an image, and it was freezing the entire program.